# conditionals, testing for a number within a range

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I want to test a number to see if it is between one and three but I think my solution is ugly and basic.

Can someone suggest something better?

```
blah = ('woo','blah','foo','bah')
if int(tmpword[2]) >= 1 or int(tmpword[2]) >= len(blah):
        return False, bpoints[int(tmpword[2])-1]
else:
        return False, word
```

`tmpword` is some number I'm pulling out of a string. I just want to test if that number is between 1 and the length of 'blah'

Comment: One way to make this code less ugly would be to store `int(tmpword[2]) ` in a variable, and refer to that variable the 3 places you are currently referencing `int(tmpword[2])`

Comment: very true, but still i wasnt aware of the more elegant solutions offered here as im a luddite :)

Comment: actually i write in lower case on purpose, please stop editing my posts. thankyou.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if 1 <= int(tmpword[2]) <= len(blah):
```

etc.

By the way, your existing code doesn't do what you want either.  You probably meant

```
if int(tmpword[2]) >= 1 and int(tmpword[2]) <= len(blah):
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
def test(tmpword):
  return 1 <= int(tmpword) <= len(blah)
```

Comment: I think you need to change `<` for `<=`

Comment: 1 is also a valid answer and `num` is now `tmpword` :)